# How do I eliminate n-consecutive values from a vector or a list?

Tags: r, list, vector

Suppose I have:

```
v <- c(1,2,0,0,0,3,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,5,0)
v
 [1] 1 2 0 0 0 3 4 4 4 0 0 0 0 5 0
```

I would like to eliminate any consecutive 0's where the number of consecutive 0's is 2+ (2 or more). So the example above would turn into:

```
1 2 3 4 4 4 5 0
```

> NOTE: I would prefer a base-R solution but other solutions would be
>   interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) na.locf0** This uses the zoo package but is only one line of code. It makes use of the `maxgap` argument in `na.locf0`.  Replace each 0 with an NA and everything else with 0. Use `na.locf0` with `maxgap` to fill it in, add it to the original vector, apply `na.omit` to remove the NAs and use `c` to remove attributes.

```
library(zoo)

c(na.omit(na.locf0(ifelse(v == 0, NA, 0), maxgap = 1) + v))
## [1] 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 0
```

**2) rleid**  This uses `rleid` from data.table.  It is a bit longer than (1) but still reasonably short.  It groups the data using `rleid` and then for each group generates an NA or the original data removing the NAs at the end.

```
library(data.table)

fun <- function(x) if (x[1] == 0 & length(x) > 1) NA else x
c(na.omit(ave(v, rleid(v), FUN = fun)))
## [1] 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 0
```

Comment: Since in the real problem I had a zoo vector already this solution best applied to my case

Answer (score 2):

An option with `rle`.  We can create a logical condition with `rle` and extract the `values` based on that

```
with(rle(v), {i1 <- !(values == 0 & lengths > 1); rep(values[i1], lengths[i1])})
#[1] 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 0
```

Note: In the previous version, the OP' output returned only a single `value`.  We just need to `rep`licate with the `lengths` using the same logic

---

Or it can be made more compact with `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
v[!(ave(v, rleid(v), FUN = length) > 1 & !v)]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) solution in `base`:

```r
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub("(0\\,){2,}","",paste0(v,collapse=",")),",")))

 # [1] 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 0
```

***N.B.*** In your question you said *where the number of consecutive 0's is 2+*, but your example was 3+ consecutive zeros; change `{2,}` to `{3,}` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Another base R way using `ave` and `head` and `tail` to compare consecutive values

```
v[!ave(v == 0, cumsum(c(TRUE, head(v, -1) != tail(v, -1))), 
               FUN = function(x) all(x) & length(x) >= 2)]

#[1] 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 0
```